# Queuing EF queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, async-await

in a windows desktop app, where context lives as long as the view lives, what would be the best way to avoid 'A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed' error?

In my view model I receive an instance of repository (through constructor), which wraps a single long-lived instance of DbContext, When I need to load some data, for example, if I do it from the same method, then I can just await for each of them in the async method, which ensures they are executed synchronously.

However, imagine that I have this:

```
private async void SomeMethodA()
{
    await Context.GetA();
}

private async void SomeMethodB()
{
    await Context.GetB();
}
```

They are declared as void since they are actually some event handlers. So, my code executes SomeMethodA(), and this database call could require 2 seconds. So, code execution returns to UI thread, and then something (user or code) triggers SomeMethodB(), which is going to raise above mentioned exception.

What would be the best way to ensure that async database calls are queued? is the repository the best place to handle this?

Comment: Repository pattern is desgined to separate your domain model from your bussines logic and this will not help you in this use case. In your example you have a bussines rules problem, you are using async await. for example when  you call SomeMethodA then the method button for the method someMethodB() shall be disabled until method A is done or waiting for TaskA to be finished by using TaskCompletionSource which helping you for the continuation.

Comment: @BassamAlugili SomeMethodB could be called by code snippet, like some event from some listener, timer, etc. So, I cannot depend on disabling anything, it does not have to be user interaction.

Comment: @StephenCleary has give you an answer. he is the multi tasking king in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what would be the best way to avoid 'A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed' error?

Always `await` your asynchronous calls.

> I can just await for each of them in the async method, which ensures they are executed synchronously.

They'll be executed asynchronously, not synchronously. However, they'll be executed *serially* (one at a time), which I think is what you meant.

> They are declared as void since they are actually some event handlers.

And that's your problem. They *must* be awaited. They *cannot* be event handlers, sorry. You'll have to modify this part of the application design. Even if you work around this (e.g., by having multiple db connections open per request), you'll still run into problems due to `async void` with the "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending" exception.

> code execution returns to UI thread

There's no UI thread here. The execution just returns to the caller.

Comment: Regarding no event handlers, say I have this scenario: I have a listener which checks every x seconds for some information. So, every x seconds an event is raised. Now, a user starts some action which triggers SomeMethodA, and then a listener immediately after gets some information which requires SomeMethodB to be executed. Obviously those two calls are going to be overlapped, which will raise an exception. So far what I gathered on internet, it seems that AsyncLock could be the solution here, will see after I do some tests.

Comment: @Goran: Yes, you can use `AsyncLock` for mutual exclusion of asynchronous code.

Answer (score 1):

You may be better to make your context local to the methods that use it, as described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx and several SO answers. I don't know much about await, but my first guess would be something like:

```
private async void SomeMethodA()
{
    using (var myContext = new Context()) // or, possibly, new Entities()
    {
        await myContext.GetA();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you read that same article that you linked, you will notice that they advise to use a context instance per form in a desktop application (ex WPF) - long lived, not short lived.